# Intervention/image plugin does not work on Docker Laravel image

Tags: docker, nginx

I combined Laravel, Nginx, and MySQL in one docker image. Everything is fine except images are not showing when I deploy docker image. 
When I have several tests on my local PC with Laravel source, the intervention images are successfully shown.
On the docker image, the intervention images are like this on inspect dialog.

```
<img class="lazy" src="/img/placeholder.png" data-src="/assets/logos/c200x90/hallon.png" width="100" height="45" alt="Hallon">
```

And on my local PC, the intervention image looks like this on inspect dialog

```
<img class="lazy" src="/assets/logos/c200x90/hallon.png" width="100" height="45" alt="Hallon" style="">
```

Even though Laravel sources are the same, I don't know why this happened?

Comment: have you checked the other requirements for this plugin? See https://github.com/Intervention/image

Answer (score 2):

I think that is the php setting problem.
Try to add the following config cmd to php.ini.

`extension=gd`

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been wasting so many hours to solve this problem and you hit my end point. Really thank you.

Comment: adding `extension=gd` not helped me